# ASP Retrieving database records, and then retrieving more records from another table using the first records

Tags: sql, asp-classic

bit of a weird one. I have got a table in a database that stores ID's for records in another table. I need to retrieve and somehow store the information from table1.

Information:
Product, Image ID, Quantity

So the Image ID will be the ID of the record in table2. Which I will then use to get that record. With that record I will find the save location of the image, and write the image onto the document the same number of times that is stored in the quantity value for that product.

Hope you understand how I need this to work. Here is some example data.

```
-Product 1-
Product -> "KR"
Image ID -> 772
Quantity -> 2

-Product 2-
Product -> "KR"
Image ID -> 774
Quantity -> 5

-Product 3-
Product -> "LR"
Image ID -> 776
Quantity -> 1
```

Now using the above data, get data from table2 using the Image ID as the rows Unique ID and store the save location.

This is what i'm trying at the moment, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<!--#include virtual="nightclub_photography\asp\functions.asp"-->
<%
'Connect to database
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
conn.Open Server.MapPath("/nightclub_photography/data/database/jamsnaps.mdb")

'Get the current date
today = ISODate(Request.Cookies("sdate") & " 00:00:00")

'Query the database for sales
sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE DATEVALUE(saleDate) = " & today & " AND printed = 0 ORDER BY product"
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

Set sales = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

if rs.EOF then
    response.write "No sales found!"
else
    do until rs.EOF
        'response.write rs("product")&":"&rs("quantity")&", "
        if sales.Exists(rs("product")) then
            sales.Item("product") = ","&rs("jpgId")&":"&rs("quantity")
        else
            sales.Add rs("product"), rs("jpgId")&":"&rs("quantity")
        end if      

        'Move to next sale
        rs.MoveNext
    loop
end if

rs.close
conn.close
%>
```

**Update 1**
Getting an error, simplified it a bit for now, just want to get it getting some results first.

Error:
`Type mismatch in expression.`

Query:
`sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID IN (SELECT jpgId FROM sales WHERE printed = 0)"`

So, using the jpgId from row numbered "2." will return the row with the same ID labeled "1.". It will do this for each sale row.

[image: See image]

Comment: Based on the title, most of the time the correct solution is the re-write things using only one query that **joins** the two parts together.

Comment: Also, looking into the query a bit, the code here uses a technique that is vulnerable to sql injection attacks and should be avoided. This particular query is okay, but based on what I see, I bet you have others that are just begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - The "application" will only ever be on local machines and used by employees. It's all run from a HTA file so ASP is needed. I use PHP on live websites and account for SQL Injection. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Many hacks are inside jobs. Internal-facing employee-only sites don't excuse vulnerable code, especially when the solution is so easy.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, it's not for a major company, it's a small nightclub photography team that just sell keyrings. No employee's will even know where to start to do SQL Injection. I see your point though, I'm planning on re-coding the entire "program" with C# once this one functions, only need to make this web based on print the products.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding but you might try something like this

select id,* from mytable where id in (select id from mytable2 where salesdate = date and printed= 0)

update mytable2 printed = 1 where id = " & myid

Comment: Any ideas George Scott?